# Incorrect results from Md5 sum in bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, md5

I'm missing some images that should have been archived when this script runs. I think this may be to do with my indentations or my Md5 sum. I have tried everything I can think of.

here is the code with out the correct indentations:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
    echo Directory "$1" cannot be found. Please try again.
    exit
fi

if [ $# -eq 1  ]; then
    echo "usage: Phar image_path archive_path"
    exit
fi

if [ -d "$2" ]; then
    echo "archive exists"
else
    echo "the directory 'archive' does't exist. Creating directory 'archive'."
    mkdir -p ~/archive 
fi

find $1 -iname "IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG" | cat > list.txt

[ -f ~/my-documents/md5.txt ] && rm md5.txt || break 
while read line;
    do md5sum $line | xargs >> md5.txt 
done < list.txt 

sort -k 1,1 -u md5.txt | cat > uniquemd5.txt 
cut -d " " -f 2- uniquemd5.txt > uniquelist.txt 

sort uniquelist.txt -r -o uniquelist.txt
for line in $(cat uniquelist.txt)
do
    file=$(basename $line) path="$2/file"

    if [ ! -f $path ];
    then 
        cp $line $2 
    else 
        cp $line $path.JPG 
    fi 

    rm uniquelist.txt md5.txt uniquemd5.txt list.txt

done
```

Comment: Please post the actual code not an image!

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do with the script? There are a few rather confusing lines. Why `find $1 -iname "IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG" | cat > list.txt` and not `find $1 -iname "IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG"  > list.txt`. What does `xargs` do on `md5sum $line | xargs >> md5.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop

```
while read line;
    do md5sum $line | xargs >> md5.txt 
done < list.txt
```

should probably be

```
while read line;
    do md5sum "$line" 
done < list.txt > md5.txt
```

Quote parameter expansions, and it's unclear why you needed.